# how to get outerHTML with jquery in order to have it cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I found a response in a jquery forum and they made a function to do this but the result is not the same.
Here is an example that I created for an image button:

```
var buttonField = $('<input type="image" />');
    buttonField.attr('id', 'butonFshi' + lastsel);
    buttonField.val('Fshi');
    buttonField.attr('src', 'images/square-icon.png');
    if (disabled)
        buttonField.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    buttonField.val('Fshi');
    if (onblur !== undefined)
        buttonField.focusout(function () { onblur(); });
    buttonField.mouseover(function () { ndryshoImazhin(1, lastsel.toString()); });
    buttonField.mouseout(function () { ndryshoImazhin(0, lastsel.toString()); });
    buttonField.click(function () { fshiClicked(lastsel.toString()); });
```

And I have this situation:

```
 buttonField[0].outerHTML = `<INPUT id=butonFshi1 value=Fshi src="images/square-icon.png" type=image jQuery15205073038169030395="44">`
```

instead the outer function I found gives buttonField.outer()  = `<INPUT id=butonFshi1 value=Fshi src="images/square-icon.png" type=image>`

The function is:

```
$.fn.outer = function(val){
    if(val){
        $(val).insertBefore(this);
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{ return $("<div>").append($(this).clone()).html(); }
}
```

so like this I loose the handlers that I inserted.
Is there anyway to get the outerHTML with jquery in order to have it cross-browser without loosing the handlers ?!

Comment: It's not a good thing to create custom attribute, like `jQuery15205073038169030395="44"`. Instead, use jQuery function `.data(element, key, value)` to store custom data. Then, you can use `.clone(true)`, where the boolean indicates whether to copy data and events

Answer (score 0):

You don't need convert it to text first (which is what disconnects it from the handlers, only DOM nodes and other specific JavaScript objects can have events). Just insert the newly created/modified node directly, e.g.

```
$('#old-button').after(buttonField).remove();`
```

`after` returns the previous jQuery collection so the `remove` gets rid of the existing element, not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var html_text = `<INPUT id=butonFshi1 value=Fshi src="images/square-icon.png" type=image jQuery15205073038169030395="44">`
buttonField[0].html(html_text);
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the jQuery plugin from https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml. With this jQuery plugin you can get the outerHTML from the first matched element, replace a set of elements and manipulate the result in a callback function.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<span>My example</span>
```

Consider the following call:

```
var span = $("span").outerHTML();
```

The variable span is equal <span>My example</span>.

In the link above you can find more example in how to use .outerHTML() plug-in.

Comment: "how to get outerHTML with jquery in order to have it cross-browser". Not sure why this was voted down as it responds the title question.

Answer (score -2):

This should work fine:

```
var outer = buttonField.parent().html();
```

Comment: that would grab any siblings as well, and still lose the handlers.